# WPF DependencyProperty not updating GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I've created a `UserControl` that needs to display the time and date and have the ability to add 1 hour on `button click`.
**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControls.TestUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.UserControls"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Test.UserControls"
         x:Name="MyTestUserControl">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:TestUserControlViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedDateTime}"/>
    <Popup IsOpen="True">
        <Button Content="Add Hour" Command="{Binding AddHourCommand}"/>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

**View Model:**

```
public class TestUserControlViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public DateTime SelectedDateTime
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(SelectedDateTimeProperty); }
        set
        {
            //this gets called
            SetValue(SelectedDateTimeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateTimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDateTime",
            typeof(DateTime),
            typeof(TestUserControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));



    #region AddHour Command
    private CommandBase _addHourCommand;
    public CommandBase AddHourCommand
    {
        get { return _addHourCommand ?? (_addHourCommand = new CommandBase(AddHour)); }
    }
    private void AddHour(object obj)
    {
        //this gets called
        SelectedDateTime = SelectedDateTime.AddHours(1);
        //Selected date is changed
    }
    #endregion
}
```

However, even when the actual `DependencyProperty` changes the display is not being affected by that change.

Answer (score 2):

1. In 99.9% of the cases you don't need to use dependency properties in your viewmodel. This is also true in this case. Use a standard CLR property instead.
2. Don't inherit from `DependencyObject` - it's unnecessary.
3. [Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx) to allow the UI to get notifications when property values change so it can update.

Comment: This is also true if I want to bind to the `SelectedDate` value from the `UserConrol`'s host?

Comment: From my experience you will have to use a DependencyProperty in that case.

Comment: But, sorry i forgot to add, i used a DependencyProperty in the code behind of the UserControl, not in the respective view model.

Comment: If you intend to reuse this user control you should not set its DataContext internally, but have the host bind it himself. In that case you should not have a view model at all, and only have the usercontrol define  its dependency properties and bind to them internally. Have a look here for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms745025(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'd say 100%. You should strictly avoid to have dependency properties in view models.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. (see [INotifyPropertyChanged on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

You'll have to "tell" the GUI that some value has been changed and it has to re-read it from the bound value.

Comment: This works, how ever, I was under the assumption that `DependencyProperty` supports property changed notifications on its own.